# ffmpeg blend filter does not work properly

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm doing my android project which uses blend filter to create uncover down video transition. My test device is Samsung S4 (Android version : 4.4.2)
this is my command string :

```
ffmpeg 
-loop 1 -t 1 -i img001.jpg 
-loop 1 -t 1 -i img002.jpg 
-loop 1 -t 1 -i img003.jpg 
-loop 1 -t 1 -i img004.jpg 
-loop 1 -t 1 -i img005.jpg 
-filter_complex 
"[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='if(lte(Y,N*H/24),A,B)'[b1v];
[2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='if(lte(Y,H*N/24),A,B)'[b2v];
[3:v][2:v]blend=all_expr='if(lte(Y,H*N/24),A,B)'[b3v];
[4:v][3:v]blend=all_expr='if(lte(Y,H*N/24),A,B)'[b4v];
[0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v][b3v][3:v][b4v]
[4:v]concat=n=9:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out_cover_top.mp4 -y
```

The expected output is that the top image (yellow) will uncover from the top to the bottom of bottom image (red) like this : 
[image]

I tested in my PC (windows 7) it's right, but this is what I get in android
[image]

My logcat :

> onProgress: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>   onProgress:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
>   onProgress:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
>   onProgress:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
>   onProgress:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
>   onProgress:   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
>   onProgress:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
>   onProgress:   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
>   onProgress:   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
>   onProgress:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
>   onProgress:   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
>   onProgress: [mjpeg @ 0x43240d90] Changing bps to 8
>   onProgress: Input #0, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/com.example.mrtai.test_animationtovideo/temporary/0.jpg':
>   onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4096 kb/s
>   onProgress:     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   onProgress: [mjpeg @ 0x43242a70] Changing bps to 8
>   onProgress: Input #1, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/com.example.mrtai.test_animationtovideo/temporary/1.jpg':
>   onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4971 kb/s
>   onProgress:     Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   onProgress: [mjpeg @ 0x43280780] Changing bps to 8
>   onProgress: Input #2, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/com.example.mrtai.test_animationtovideo/temporary/2.jpg':
>   onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9413 kb/s
>   onProgress:     Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   onProgress: [mjpeg @ 0x43244260] Changing bps to 8
>   onProgress: Input #3, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/com.example.mrtai.test_animationtovideo/temporary/3.jpg':
>   onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4096 kb/s
>   onProgress:     Stream #3:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x438292b0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x438320f0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x4383af40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x44044100] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x4404cf50] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x44055d90] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x4405ebe0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x44067a20] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x44070870] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x440796b0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: [libx264 @ 0x43df2fd0] using SAR=1/1
>   onProgress: [libx264 @ 0x43df2fd0] using cpu capabilities: none!
>   onProgress: [libx264 @ 0x43df2fd0] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
>   onProgress: [libx264 @ 0x43df2fd0] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
>   onProgress: Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/com.example.mrtai.test_animationtovideo/saves/test.mp4':
>   onProgress:   Metadata:
>   onProgress:     encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
>   onProgress:     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
>   onProgress:     Metadata:
>   onProgress:       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
>   onProgress:     Side data:
>   onProgress:       unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
>   onProgress: Stream mapping:
>   onProgress:   Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> blen>bottom
>   onProgress:   Stream #0:0 (mjpeg) -> concat:in0:v0
>   onProgress:   Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> blen>top
>   onProgress:   Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> blen>bottom
>   onProgress:   Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> concat:in2:v0
>   onProgress:   Stream #2:0 (mjpeg) -> blen>top
>   onProgress:   Stream #2:0 (mjpeg) -> blen>bottom
>   onProgress:   Stream #2:0 (mjpeg) -> concat:in4:v0
>   onProgress:   Stream #3:0 (mjpeg) -> blen>top
>   onProgress:   Stream #3:0 (mjpeg) -> concat:in6:v0
>   onProgress:   format -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
>   onProgress: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   onProgress: frame=   16 fps=0.0 q=12.0 size=      51kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate=1171.2kbits/s speed=0.685x
>   onProgress: frame=   29 fps= 25 q=25.0 size=      64kB time=00:00:00.88 bitrate= 593.2kbits/s speed=0.762x
>   onProgress: frame=   33 fps= 19 q=25.0 size=      72kB time=00:00:01.04 bitrate= 565.8kbits/s speed=0.611x
>   onProgress: frame=   37 fps= 17 q=16.0 size=     113kB time=00:00:01.20 bitrate= 769.9kbits/s speed=0.537x
>   onProgress: frame=   41 fps= 15 q=13.0 size=     147kB time=00:00:01.36 bitrate= 886.3kbits/s speed=0.495x
>   onProgress: frame=   46 fps= 14 q=12.0 size=     180kB time=00:00:01.56 bitrate= 943.1kbits/s speed=0.463x
>   onProgress: frame=   50 fps= 13 q=12.0 size=     188kB time=00:00:01.72 bitrate= 896.8kbits/s speed=0.439x
>   onProgress: frame=   77 fps= 17 q=12.0 size=     209kB time=00:00:02.80 bitrate= 610.9kbits/s speed=0.63x
>   onProgress: frame=   82 fps= 16 q=27.0 size=     213kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate= 580.6kbits/s speed=0.594x
>   onProgress: frame=   87 fps= 15 q=17.0 size=     288kB time=00:00:03.20 bitrate= 737.1kbits/s speed=0.566x
>   onProgress: frame=   91 fps= 15 q=13.0 size=     349kB time=00:00:03.36 bitrate= 851.1kbits/s speed=0.536x
>   onProgress: frame=   95 fps= 14 q=12.0 size=     407kB time=00:00:03.52 bitrate= 946.2kbits/s speed=0.515x
>   onProgress: frame=  100 fps= 13 q=12.0 size=     416kB time=00:00:03.72 bitrate= 917.1kbits/s speed=0.501x
>   onProgress: frame=  128 fps= 16 q=17.0 size=     429kB time=00:00:04.84 bitrate= 725.7kbits/s speed=0.604x
>   onProgress: frame=  133 fps= 16 q=24.0 size=     438kB time=00:00:05.04 bitrate= 712.4kbits/s speed=0.589x
>   onProgress: frame=  138 fps= 15 q=14.0 size=     487kB time=00:00:05.24 bitrate= 761.2kbits/s speed=0.577x
>   onProgress: frame=  142 fps= 15 q=12.0 size=     519kB time=00:00:05.40 bitrate= 787.4kbits/s speed=0.564x
>   onProgress: frame=  147 fps= 14 q=12.0 size=     545kB time=00:00:05.60 bitrate= 796.5kbits/s speed=0.551x
>   onProgress: frame=  175 fps= 16 q=12.0 size=     561kB time=00:00:06.72 bitrate= 683.7kbits/s speed=0.619x
>   onProgress: frame=  175 fps= 16 q=-1.0 Lsize=     566kB time=00:00:07.00 bitrate= 662.9kbits/s speed=0.642x
>   onProgress: video:565kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhea> 0.262062%
>   onProgress: [libx264 @ 0x43df2fd0] frame I:1     Avg QP:20.00  size: 28930
>   onProgress: [libx264 @ 0x43df2fd0] frame P:174   Avg QP:14.14  size:  3155
>   onProgress: [libx264 @ 0x43df2fd0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
>   onProgress: [libx264 @ 0x43df2fd0] mb P  I16..4:  1.7%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 28.8%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:69.4%
>   onProgress: [libx264 @ 0x43df2fd0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 74.7% 79.5% 49.5% inter: 11.8% 14.3% 5.3%
>   onProgress: [libx264 @ 0x43df2fd0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 19% 46% 18% 18%
>   onProgress: [libx264 @ 0x43df2fd0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 26% 46% 17% 11%
>   onProgress: [libx264 @ 0x43df2fd0] kb/s:660.46
>   onSuccess: -------------------------
>   onFinish:

Logcat of setSar behavior :

> onProgress: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>   onProgress:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
>   onProgress:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
>   onProgress:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
>   onProgress:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
>   onProgress:   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
>   onProgress:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
>   onProgress:   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
>   onProgress:   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
>   onProgress:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
>   onProgress:   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
>   onProgress: [mjpeg @ 0x41be8890] Changing bps to 8
>   onProgress: Input #0, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/test.jpg':
>   onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16530 kb/s
>   onProgress:     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 900x900 [SAR 300:300 DAR 1:1], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x41b1c020] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: Output #0, image2, to '/storage/emulated/0/com.example.mrtai.test_animationtovideo/temporary/0.jpg':
>   onProgress:   Metadata:
>   onProgress:     encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
>   onProgress:     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   onProgress:     Metadata:
>   onProgress:       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 mjpeg
>   onProgress:     Side data:
>   onProgress:       unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
>   onProgress: Stream mapping:
>   onProgress:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mjpeg (native))
>   onProgress: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   onProgress: frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=4.6 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.293x
>   onProgress: video:20kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhea> unknown
>   onSuccess: -------------------------
>   onFinish: 
>   onProgress: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>   onProgress:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
>   onProgress:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
>   onProgress:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
>   onProgress:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
>   onProgress:   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
>   onProgress:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
>   onProgress:   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
>   onProgress:   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
>   onProgress:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
>   onProgress:   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
>   onProgress: [mjpeg @ 0x41ffe890] Changing bps to 8
>   onProgress: Input #0, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/test2.jpg':
>   onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14981 kb/s
>   onProgress:     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 720x960 [SAR 72:72 DAR 3:4], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x420171b0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: Output #0, image2, to '/storage/emulated/0/com.example.mrtai.test_animationtovideo/temporary/1.jpg':
>   onProgress:   Metadata:
>   onProgress:     encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
>   onProgress:     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   onProgress:     Metadata:
>   onProgress:       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 mjpeg
>   onProgress:     Side data:
>   onProgress:       unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
>   onProgress: Stream mapping:
>   onProgress:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mjpeg (native))
>   onProgress: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   onProgress: frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=5.8 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.428x
>   onProgress: video:24kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhea> unknown
>   onSuccess: -------------------------
>   onFinish: 
>   onProgress: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>   onProgress:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
>   onProgress:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
>   onProgress:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
>   onProgress:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
>   onProgress:   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
>   onProgress:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
>   onProgress:   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
>   onProgress:   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
>   onProgress:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
>   onProgress:   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
>   onProgress: [mjpeg @ 0x42dac890] Changing bps to 8
>   onProgress: Input #0, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/test3.jpg':
>   onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6901 kb/s
>   onProgress:     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 500x283, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x42dcd8a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: Output #0, image2, to '/storage/emulated/0/com.example.mrtai.test_animationtovideo/temporary/2.jpg':
>   onProgress:   Metadata:
>   onProgress:     encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
>   onProgress:     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   onProgress:     Metadata:
>   onProgress:       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 mjpeg
>   onProgress:     Side data:
>   onProgress:       unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
>   onProgress: Stream mapping:
>   onProgress:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mjpeg (native))
>   onProgress: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   onProgress: frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=6.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.497x
>   onProgress: video:46kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhea> unknown
>   onSuccess: -------------------------
>   onFinish: 
>   onProgress: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>   onProgress:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
>   onProgress:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
>   onProgress:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
>   onProgress:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
>   onProgress:   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
>   onProgress:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
>   onProgress:   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
>   onProgress:   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
>   onProgress:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
>   onProgress:   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
>   onProgress: [mjpeg @ 0x4228a890] Changing bps to 8
>   onProgress: Input #0, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/test.jpg':
>   onProgress:   Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16530 kb/s
>   onProgress:     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 900x900 [SAR 300:300 DAR 1:1], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   onProgress: [swscaler @ 0x422a31b0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
>   onProgress: Output #0, image2, to '/storage/emulated/0/com.example.mrtai.test_animationtovideo/temporary/3.jpg':
>   onProgress:   Metadata:
>   onProgress:     encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
>   onProgress:     Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 480x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
>   onProgress:     Metadata:
>   onProgress:       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 mjpeg
>   onProgress:     Side data:
>   onProgress:       unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
>   onProgress: Stream mapping:
>   onProgress:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mjpeg (native))
>   onProgress: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
>   onProgress: frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=4.6 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A speed=0.533x
>   onProgress: video:20kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhea> unknown
>   onSuccess: -------------------------
>   onFinish:

Help me please.

Comment: Can you show an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: @Gyan I updated my question, please help me.

Comment: Share full log of the android run.

Comment: @Gyan I added logcat, please check it.

Comment: The logs don't show anything unusual. Is the desktop version of ffmpeg the same? Also, generate new log by adding -report to the android run.

Comment: @Gyan The problem just occur when creating uncover down (uncover from the top to the bottom),  when I change Y to X (to create uncover from left to right) it work. Something wrong with Y. 


p/s I'm not good in English, sorry about this